# how can I make a button click function be clicked multiple times?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an application with topics and a paragraph under the topic.

When the user clicks on the topic it sets the paragraph visible and on re-click it sets it to gone. It can only be clicked once, how can I make it happen 10 times? without writing the function 10 times

I have tried adding recreate(); under b1.setTextColor, it only recreates the function. I also have the same function for topic b2,b3,b4 etc. When all the topics are clicked and visibility changed to VISIBLE, the user presses on b1 to close it, it sets all the other topics visibility to GONE.

```
        final LinearLayout lb1 = findViewById(R.id.b_title1a);
        final TextView b1 = findViewById(R.id.b_title1);
        b1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                lb1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                b1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        lb1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        b1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Is there a way to repeat the function or how to loop it?
By-means the user stays on activity and be-able to open and close a topic as many times as the user can.

```
     b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                lb1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                b1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        lb1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        b1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                        recreate();

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

This works, but the code is not clean it gives problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is: the first time you click on the topic you show the paragraph, but then you override the method so it will hide it. But when you do so, you lose the ability to show it back.

You don't need to override the OnClick method after the first click. Use an if statement to see if the view is visible. If it is, hide it. If not, show it.

```
final LinearLayout lb1 = findViewById(R.id.b_title1a);
final TextView b1 = findViewById(R.id.b_title1);
b1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (lb1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            lb1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            b1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        } else {
            lb1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            b1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I will go and try that now, Thanks

Comment: The code works basically the same as mine, but it still does not make the function repeat. I can only click once to show and once to hide.

Comment: I think I might have miscomprehended your question. What do you mean by wanting to repeat? Do you want it to show and hide several times by only clicking on it once?

Comment: I want to user to be-able to open and close the topic as many times the user wants while still browsing the activity.

Comment: Try it again, changing v.getVisibility() to lb1.getVisibility(), as I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked, I have struggling for days now.

Answer (score 1):

Set a boolean Flag globally

```
Flag = true;
```

Then on button click, if the flag is true then it means button is clicked to show the paragraph, so write the code to show the paragraph and change the Flag to false

Next time, when button is clicked, the Flag will false and then you can execute the code to hide the paragraph.

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick (View v){
        if (Flag) {
            lb1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            b1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        } else {
            lb1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            b1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to use a flag for this. There are other ways to check the visibility of the view. This way, if anything else changes the visibility of the view you will have to remember to change the flag or the code will work incorrectly. This flag will only haunt your code.